# Self executing function and the document.write

Tags: javascript

I have this self-executing function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var sc      = document.createElement('script'); 
    sc.src   = 'http://blahblah.com/test.js';
    sc.type = 'text/javascript'; 

var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, s);
})();
</script>
```

All that is contained in test.js is:

```
document.write('ping!');
```

However, it hangs -- am I doing something incorrect?

I found a way to go around the document.write but now the only question is why does this not work.

```
var nc = document.createElement('div');  
nc.appendChild(document.createTextNode('blah'));  
var scr = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];  
scr.parentNode.insertBefore(nc, scr);
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Does it hang on all browsers? Is there anything else in the script that could potentially cause the browser to hang? I wrote some simple tests similar to your code, and they work fine on Firefox, Safari, and Chrome.

Comment: Here's a version of the working script you can [checkout](http://anurag.heroku.com/tests/remoteDocWrite/index.html). The JavaScript is [test.js](http://anurag.heroku.com/tests/remoteDocWrite/test.js). The page initially starts with the text "World!" which gets replaced by a new document showing "Hello" after the remote script is loaded.

Comment: @Anurag, in firefox it never stops loading.

Comment: I see the forever loading spinner too, but it's a problem with Firefox. The page does load, and didn't hang in the conventional sense - blue screen of death or ctrl+alt+del kind.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish, but your code is valid as long as it's hosted on `http://blahblah.com/`.

Your browser won't let you execute remote code to manipulate the original page. It's not *that* dumb.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with running remote scripts. The catch is when they try and manipulate the DOM, etc.

Comment: Not quite, including external scripts in this way is perfectly valid, that's how [JSON-P](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) works for example... The real problem is [`document.write`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)...

Comment: >Your browser won't let you execute remote code to manipulate the original page. It's not that dumb.

ummm that's not true.

Comment: Dolph is right, if both scripts are not on the same domain it won't work. Not that way. JSON-P is working because what is fetched is eval'ed by a local script.
This to work one has to download http://blahblah.com/test.js in a string then eval that string.

Comment: @Claude @Dolph - that is not true. The remote script will have equal rights unless it's inside an iframe, and domains mismatch.

Comment: I'm not aware of a standard for JavaScript security practices. If that's the case, browsers may implement and enforce their own proprietary security policies differently.